# mcrypt not decrypting to same length

Tags: php, json, mcrypt

I am trying to mcrypt some data using a class I created (methods below). This is how you mcrypt data then using pack, then you can use unpack to get the data back.

```
$packed = $server->cache->pack("packed", array(123,123,123), "Password");
if(!$packed){
    echo "Could not encrypt data\n";
}
$server->cache->unpack("packed", "Password");
```

when I pack it, I do a `var_dump` on the `json_encode()` data, and get this:
`string(13) "[123,123,123]"`

When I unpack it, I do a `var_dump` on the `mcrypt_decode()` string, and get this:
`string(32) "[123,123,123]"`

Why are the lengths different? When I do a `json_decode()` on the `mcrypt_decode()` string, I get `null` back, and this is the reason. If I trim the data it works, but I shouldn't have to trim it.

Here are the methods:

```
<?php
public function put($key, $value, $life = 0)
{
    $this->cache[$key] = $value;
    $life              = (int)$life;
    if($life > 0)
    {
        $life = strtotime("now + $life seconds");
    }

    $this->life[$key] = $life;
}

public function get($key)
{
    return $this->cache[$key];
}

public function pack($key, $value, $secret, $life = 0)
{
    if(!function_exists("mcrypt_encrypt"))
    {
        $this->put($key, $value, $life);
        return false;
    }
    $iv_size   = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv        = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $value     = json_encode($value);
    var_dump($value);
    $cryptdata = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret, $value, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    $this->put($key, $cryptdata, $life);
    return true;
}

public function unpack($key, $secret)
{
    if(!function_exists("mcrypt_decrypt"))
    {
        return json_decode($this->get($key), true);
    }
    $cryptdata = $this->get($key);
    $iv_size   = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
    $iv        = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $data      = mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $secret, $cryptdata, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv);
    //$data      = json_decode($data, true);
    var_dump($data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When using a block cipher mode like ECB (you shouldn't be using that one btw), MCrypt will NUL-pad the data, so that its length is dividable by the encryption algorithm's block size.

If you must know, for Rijndael-256 the block size is 256 bits or 32 bytes.

Considering that you're encrypting JSON data, you can just `rtrim()` the data and not worry about it. There's no way around that unless you switch to a counter mode like CTR.